# How to return array value in magento soap API wsi.xml?

Tags: magento-1.9, soap-api-v2, wsdl

I have created a file wsi.xml in magento 1.9 soap API. It is returning empty object. I have provided the array value for the response function. But showing empty value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"
             xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
             xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             name="{{var wsdl.name}}"
             targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
            <xsd:complexType name="testPushNotification">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="notification_id" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="notification_title" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="message" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="created_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                    <xsd:element name="updated_at" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:complexType name="testPushNotificationArray">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="complexObjectArray" type="typens:testPushNotification" />
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>        
            <xsd:element name="dzPushnotifSystemListRequestParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="sessionId" type="xsd:string" />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="dzPushnotifSystemListResponseParam">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="result" type="xsd:string"  />
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>   
        </xsd:schema>     
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="dzPushnotifSystemListRequest">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:dzPushnotifSystemListRequestParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="dzPushnotifSystemListResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="typens:dzPushnotifSystemListResponseParam" />
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
       <wsdl:operation name="dzPushnotifSystemList">
            <wsdl:documentation>TEST</wsdl:documentation>
            <wsdl:input message="typens:dzPushnotifSystemListRequest" />
            <wsdl:output message="typens:dzPushnotifSystemListResponse" />
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding" type="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}PortType">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="dzPushnotifSystemList">
            <soap:operation soapAction="" />
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="{{var wsdl.name}}Service">
        <wsdl:port name="{{var wsdl.handler}}Port" binding="typens:{{var wsdl.handler}}Binding">
            <soap:address location="{{var wsdl.url}}" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Any help?

Comment: you need to convert your array to XML

Comment: Where should I need to add the code?